# no idea where to start: 'calculator-like' rails app that displays a keypad user can click to type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I need my webapp to display a 'keypad' on the screen that makes special-purpose data entry very easy... can't be flash since needs to work with ipad (and also work from regular pc/browser/ mouse).

The simplest variation would be a 'calculator' app where they press number keys and functioin keys and the app takes the input and displays results.

we very specifically need to provide data input from our webapp screen by click/touch 'keys' -- not from the PC keyboard (or soft keyboard on ipad)

I have no idea where to start... any ideas would be appreciated! For example is there some nifty ajax and/or jquery thingy that lets you build an input keypad?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/davidnorth/JsReckoner you can take this repo for your base and modify it. Good luck